# bash for with awk command inside

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk

i have this piece of code of a bash script

```
for file in "$(ls | grep .*.c)"
do
cat $file |awk '/.*open/{print $0}'|awk -v nomeprog=$file 'BEGIN{FS="(";printf "the file e %s with the  open call:", nameprog}//{ print $2}'
done
```

**this give me this error :
*awk: cmd. line:1: file.c 
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error**

*i have this error when i have more of a file c into the folder , with just 1 file it works

Comment: can't you just do `awk '... your script ...' *.c | awk '..more scripts...'` ?

Comment: i have to create a BASH shell script which, for each ".c" file in the current directory,
 list all files opened by that program with the system call open.

Comment: That still gives you no good reason for this. There's [no good reason to use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and no good reason to use `cat`.

Comment: You have lost the 2 line formatting where `awk` is using the `^` char to "point" to where the error is  in your code. Use 4 spaces at the front of a line that should be displayed as code/data/errMsgs or use the `{}` tool on mouse selected text for same. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, `exec 3<somefile` uses the `open()` call to open `somefile` (and then a call in the `fdup()` family to copy the file descriptor it was automatically assigned to FD number 3). I don't know what you're using `awk` for here at all.

Comment: Edit your Q to show one small sample and the required output  from that sample and we can simplify your solution (probably). Good luck.

Comment: ...or you're trying to find C programs that contain the string `open(`? `grep -e 'open(' *.c`. Or, much better, use a program that actually knows how to parse C source code to index your source files and read its results; see, f/e, [CScope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). `awk` and `grep` can't correctly parse comments, macros, etc; anything you get from them will be suspect at best.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you should probably follow Charles Duffy's recommendation to use more appropriate tools for the task. But I'd like to go over why the current script isn't working and how to fix it, as a learning exercise.

Also, two quick recommendations for shell script checking & troubleshooting: run your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to point out common mistakes, and when debugging put `set -x` before the problem section (and `set +x` after), so the shell will print out what it thinks is going on as the script runs.

The problem is due to how you're using the `file` variable. Let's look at what this does:

```
for file in "$(ls | grep .*.c)"
```

First, `ls` prints a list of files in the current directory, one per line. `ls` is really intended for interactive use, and its output can be ambiguous and hard to parse correctly; in a script, there are almost always [better ways to get lists of filenames](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (and I'll show you one in a bit).

The output of `ls` is piped to `grep .*.c`, which is wrong in a number of ways. First, since that pattern contains a wildcard character ("`*`"), the shell will try to expand it into a list of matching filenames. If the directory contains any hidden (with a leading ".") .c files, it'll replace it with a list of those, and nothing is going to work at all right. **Always** quote the pattern argument to `grep` to prevent this.

But the pattern itself ("`.*.c`") is also wrong; it searches for any number of arbitrary characters ("`.*`"), followed by a single arbitrary character ("`.`" -- this is in a regex, so "`.`" is not treated literally), followed by a "c". And it searches for this *anywhere in the line*, so any filename that contains a "c" somewhere other than the first position will match. The pattern you want would be something like `'[.]c$'` (note that I wrapped it in single-quotes, so the shell won't try to treat `$` as a variable reference like it would in double-quotes).

Then there's another problem, which is (part of) the problem you're actually experiencing: the output of that `ls | grep` is expanded *in double-quotes*. The double-quotes around it tell the shell not to do its usual word-split-and-wildcard-expand thing on the result. The common (but still wrong) thing to do here is to leave off the double-quotes, because word-splitting will probably break the list of filenames up into individual filenames, so you can iterate over them one-by-one. (Unless any filenames contain funny characters, in which case it can give weird results.) But with double-quotes it doesn't split them, it just treats the whole thing as one big item, so your loop runs once with `file` set to "`src1.c\nsrc2.c\nsrc3.c`" (where the `\n`'s represent actual newlines).

This is the sort of trouble you can get into by parsing `ls`. Don't do it, just use a shell wildcard directly:

```
for file in *.c
```

This is much simpler, avoids all the confusion about regex pattern syntax vs wildcard pattern syntax, ambiguity in `ls`'s output, etc. It's simple, clear, and it *just works*.

That's probably enough to get it to work for you, but there are a couple of other things you really should fix if you're doing something like this. First, you should double-quote variable references (i.e. use `"$file"` instead of just `$file`). This, is another part of the error you're getting; look at the second `awk` command:

```
awk -v nomeprog=$file 'BEGIN{FS="(";printf "the file e %s with the  open call:", nameprog}//{ print $2}'
```

With `file` set to "`src1.c\nsrc2.c\nsrc3.c`", the shell will do its word-split-and-wildcard-expand thing on it, giving:

```
awk -v nomeprog=src1.c src2.c src3.c 'BEGIN{FS="(";printf "the file e %s with the  open call:", nameprog}//{ print $2}'
```

`awk` will thus set its `nomeprog` variable to "src1.c", and then try to run "src2.c" as an awk command (on input files named "src3.c" and "BEGIN{FS=..."). "src2.c" is, of course, not a valid awk command, so you get syntax error.

This sort of confusion is typical of the chaos that can result from unquoted variable references. Double-quote your variable references.

The other thing, which is much less important, is that you have a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). Anytime you have the pattern:

```
cat somefile | somecommand
```

(and it's just a single file, not several that need to be `cat`enated together), you should just use:

```
somecommand <somefile
```

and in some cases like `awk` and `grep`, the command itself can take input filename(s) directly as arguments, so you can just use:

```
somecommand somefile
```

so in your case, rather than

```
cat "$file" | awk '/.*open/{print $0}' | awk -v nomeprog="$file" 'BEGIN{FS="(";printf "the file e %s with the  open call:", nameprog}//{ print $2}'
```

I'd just use:

```
awk '/.*open/{print $0}' "$file" | awk -v nomeprog="$file" 'BEGIN{FS="(";printf "the file e %s with the  open call:", nameprog}//{ print $2}'
```

(Although, as Charles Duffy pointed out, even *that* can be simplified quite a lot.)